# Xdebug not loading

Tags: php, xdebug

- Windows 7 64-bit
- PHP 5.3.10
- `php_xdebug-2.1.4-5.3-vc9-x86_64`

I got the correct download from pasting the output from phpinfo() [here](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php). This is what's in my `php.ini` file:

```
zend_extension = c:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.4-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll
```

I've tried with and without `_ts`. I've tried **32-bit** and **64-bit** (the wizard actually recommends the **32-bit** version for some reason).

Why isn't this working?

Comment: If the wizard suggests 32bit, you might be using PHP in 32 bit mode so better go with it ...

Comment: Try setting `display_startup_errors = On` and setting `error_log` to an actual file path (to ensure you are getting all the error output possible).  PHP should write some indication of why the extension is failing into the logs.

For example, one server I was working on was displaying this error output:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module`
`Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0`
`PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0`
`These options need to match`

Answer (score 3):

Have you added some basic configuration?

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "c:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.4-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=15
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that before, has never worked. Does it need to be configured correctly for it to show on phpinfo()?

Comment: For me it was. But that was on Mac. Have you tried to wrap your dll path to quotes (like in my example)? It is unlikely but can't see any more problems.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am a bit late to this party but I was wrestling with this today.

I followed the XDebug wizard's directions for the DLL install and setup the INI file correctly but it still wouldn't load.

The solution was that my xdebug.*.dll needed to be in folder I set in the INI file as the 'extension_dir'.
The XDebug wizard told me to put it in the 'php/' parent directory.

Hope it helps someone.

My setup: Windows 7 x64, Apache v2.4.7 VC11, PHP v5.5.9, php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll

Comment: Thanks you so much, sir. Took me ages of fiddling before I tried to explicitly set the `extension_dir` per your helpful answer. After that, it worked like a charm.

Comment: I was told by the tool to add the line:
zend_extension = ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll
but as 
extension_dir = "ext"
I had to remove the "ext\" part from the zend_extension line.
Thanks for the tip @MattyB

Answer (score 1):

For people coming here from google search. Here was my setup.

- Windows NT MY-PC 10.0 build 18362 (Windows 10) AMD64
- MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017)
- php 7.2.6
- Apache 2.4

I used the [xdebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard) to tell me which dll to download.  Here is what it came up with.

1. Download php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
2. Move the downloaded file to ext
3. Update C:\php726\php.ini and change the line

   zend_extension = ext\php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
4. Restart the webserver

It definitely got the right dll but instruction didn't end up being as straight forward as it seem because when I typed `php -m` in powershell and it always said `Failed load extension php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64`

First of all you need to make sure if yo have extension directory set in php.ini so in my case it was `extension_dir = "ext"`

If the above is the case with you, just specify the dll without full path in php.ini and you're good to go.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

You can type `php -m` to confirm xebug is loaded or throw in a php file with `phpinfo();` restart Apache and search for xdebug.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

If the wizard says you need to use the 32bit version, then you need to use the 32bit version. That bit it does *not* get wrong. But otherwise, you're not providing enough information and you need to post the first block of phpinfo() output up for people to see.