# PHP XDEBUG not getting enabled

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, php-7

Unable to enable XDEBUG. Any help or check if it is enabled and not reflected? I am on PHP7 and am using Xdebug 2.4.0rc2. PHP.INI settings below:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="C:/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 10000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1 
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "profilerlogs"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%p
```

Unable to get it enabled. The steps are right but doesnt show up installed in phpinfo() as well.

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show xdebug as enabled?

Comment: No. It not enabled there.

`Configure Command cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Debug Build no`

No entry for Xdebug below

Comment: Gary please create a PHP file with ``<?php phpinfo();`` and look there or use the command line tool ``php.exe -m`` to see a list with all enabled extensions

Comment: php -m shows xdebug but phpinfo() does not. XDebug does not function nor creates log. The path for the logs has been defined.

Comment: @ins0 any solution here. I have been struggling with the enablement. I do see xdebug in the list only using php -m not with phpinfo(). What other methods are available to check if this is enabled? I have both `php_xdebug.dll` and `php_xdebug.pdb` in the `/php/ext` folder. Am I missing something here or do I have to install all the debug files `.pdb` of php debug binary also installed? Is there a path I need to ensure or any php.ini specification I need to do?

Comment: it looks like your php pages running over cgi or fpm, so you should check in your ``phpinfo()`` output which ``php.ini`` files gets loaded and modfiy the correct ``ini`` file to add ``xdebug``

Comment: Ok. I have one php version at this moment registered both in environment variables as well as in apache. Even with php development server it does not show enabled. Am I doing something wrong that it shows up in `php -m` command? Second, What is the standard path for keeping the `.dll and .pdb files of php_xdebug` and the `php debug files provided (as download) for other extensions`? Do I need to enable others as well or just put in some specific folder? Not sure, may be I am doing this wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't install XDEBUG on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675172/cant-install-xdebug-on-windows)

Comment: No its not. The version and issue is different. However, I still am not able to use it. I have found alternatives to debug though. Strangely, though it is so difficult to get it set up and no good documentation to do it right on windows

Comment: here is an excellent tutorial that explains step by step procedure
https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem with **XAMPP** PHP7 now it's solved :)
There should be missing or wrong extention file in your `C:/php/ext/` directory.

This will solve your problem.

1. Go to [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/download.php)
2. Dowload Xdebug 2.4.0rc1 (PHP 7.0 VC14 TS 32/64)
3. Rename it to php_xdebug.dll
4. Paste this file in "php/ext" folder
5. Restart your server.

Now check your `phpinfo()`

In my case there were 64bit version so I've just changed to 32bit

Comment: I believe I did use the `rc x64` version for `php7` but did not work. In `phpinfo()` is not showing up. After installing debug browser extensions, it is setting the xdebug cookie but this is the error I get asexample `Call to undefined function xdebug_break() `. But my `php -m` does show xdebug in list of loaded extensions like @ins0 mentioned. Let me try using xampp installer and see if I can use it. May be my set up issues will get resoved. Let me try that and revert. Thanks.

Comment: it worked for me, thanks! I also had to use the 32bit ext even though i have a 64bit machine.

Comment: @CharlesBlackwell hmm... thats strange. I had to install alternative extensions

Answer (score 4):

Along with what @haider-lasani said please do not forget what type of PHP you are using. The latest XAMPP is using some really convoluted setup.

Go to your PHP folder and check whether you have php7.dll or php7ts.dll. If you have the latter version then you are supposed to pick up the TS version of xdebug. 
Also check VC version as well.In this case it is VC14.
Now even though I am using a TS version of PHP I still have to add the plugin with **zend_extension="C:/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"** and not **zend_extension_ts="C:/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"**

**TL;DR**
While downloading xdebug make sure you:

1. Check x64/x86 bit version.(Use x86 xdebug just to be safe)
2. Check what version of PHP you are using.
3. Check whether you have TS or non-TS version of PHP by checking whether you have php{x}.dll or php{x}ts.dll.{x}is your php version.
4. Try switching between zend_extension and zend_extension_ts to include your xdebug plugin in your php.ini file to see what works.

Following all these steps should ideally fix your problems. Let me know if you still are facing any problems. Peace.

Comment: Yeah these are valid points. I can manage servers so I think I might not have missed these point but let me check again.

Comment: Changing from zend_extension to zend_extension_ts was my issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to rename your DLL and it is a good idea not to, as it allows you to see what build of XDebug you have running.

Here is what I did and it works:

This answer assumes you have PHP set up with the correct PATH entry so that you can run PHP from the Command Line such as GitBash https://git-for-windows.github.io/

1. Open up your command line  and enter this:

   `$ php -i`
2. Scroll to the top and copy the output from the command line window beginning where you see

   `phpinfo()`

   ..... copy contents until you see the last line which ends:

   `If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
   questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.`
   `
3. Go the XDebug Windows Wizard https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and paste your PHPInfo in the big text box and submit.
4. A new page will display with instructions and a **"System Summary** of your PHP. Carefully follow the instructions and select the **Download** link.
5. Once you have modified your PHP.ini and observed where your "ext" folder is, copy your downloaded XDebug dll file to "ext" folder.
6. Open your command line again and enter the following command:

   `$ php -m`

If you have **correctly** followed the instructions you will see the output contains the following:

`[Zend Modules]
Xdebug`

Otherwise, you will see an error at the top of the console output such as:
      `Cannot load Xdebug`

Usually, the errors occur because your XDebug:

- is not in the correct location
- is the wrong version
- is incompatible because of thread type:  Your PHP maybe Thread Safe, and your XDebug is Not Thread Safe (the XDebug Wizard will automatically choose the correct version)

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing remote development on either a WSL or a Linux, check your php directory as you may need to modify `php.ini` files in the following locations:

`/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`

and

`/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`

with

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

;don't forget to change the path and filename to the correct one
;but make sure you use the full path

zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so"
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Xampp like a week ago. It was already installed with a php_xdebug.dll file in the ext folder.

For me the solution was to specify the xdebug file like below, without a file path:

```
zend_extension = "php_xdebug.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 10 x64 running PHP 7.2 and Apache 2.4, Specifying DLL without the full path like this

```
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
```

worked for me because my `extension_dir = "ext"` was set properly in php.ini.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58895629/3007014) is a detail set of instructions if you're using similar setup.